# Taxonomy Views filters Intersection

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

We have the following picture:

[image]

We have 4 taxonomy terms inside same filter and 2 articles: one tagged ideea&news and the other one ideea&business.

Now when you select ideea&news filters you get both articles as results. How can i change that, so i get the intersection between the selected taxonomy terms (so to have only results containing BOTH ideea&news)?

Answer (score 1):

From your view admin page, under `Advanced` section. Click on `Query settings: Settings` and make `Distinct` checked.

Hope this works.

Comment: you see.. i selected ideea&news filters, but i get among my results "post a" that has only "ideea" term assigned to it. ( i want each new filter to refine the search ) - please try to read my question again - hope you'll understand what i'm asking